# cart grows to cover div below it

Tags: html, css

I hope I am posting in the correct area. This is my first post here.

I am having a problem that only happens in IE7. I am pretty sure it is a css problem, but it involves the shopping cart in the left column of a site I am working on.

As items are added to the cart, the cart grows taller, but the div below it does not move down. Instead the cart starts to cover the div below it.

This only happens in IE7. I have been trying to fix this for days. I have tried everything I can think of in terms of css, but nothing helps. Here is a link to the test site www.palmsdining.com/. Please remember this only occurs in IE7.  Any help would be appreciated.
Attached is an image showing the problem.[image]

This is a Joomla site. Here is the index.php code:

---

```
<?php
/**
 * @version    $Id: index.php $
 * @package    test
 * @copyright  Copyright (C) 2012 test
     */
// No direct access.
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
JHTML::_('behavior.framework', true);

/* The following sets up for a modal system message pop-up window */
JHTML::_('behavior.mootools');
JHTML::_('behavior.modal');

/* The following line gets the application object for things like displaying the site name */
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$tplparams  = $app->getTemplate(true)->params;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" dir="<?php echo $this->direction; ?>">
<head>
<jdoc:include type="head" />

<!--[if lte IE 6]><script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/warning.js"></script><script>window.onload=function(){e("images/warning_imgs/")}</script><![endif]-->
<!-- The following line loads the general CSS file located in the template/css folder. -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/system/css/general.css" type="text/css" />
<!-- The following line loads the system CSS file located in the template/css folder. -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/system/css/system.css" type="text/css" />
<!-- The following line loads the main template CSS file "test styles" located in the template folder. -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/test.css" type="text/css" />
<!-- The following line loads the test TopNav style sheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/topnav_styles.css" type="text/css" />
<!-- The following line loads the test shopping modules style sheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/frontend_default.css" type="text/css" />
<!-- The following line loads the social buttons  style sheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/soc_btns_styles.css" type="text/css" />
<!-- The following line loads the ht_login mod style sheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/ht_login.css" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/hotlogin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>
<!-- The following line adds the script for the new modal system message pop-up window-->

<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
 if( $('system-message') ){
 SqueezeBox.initialize();
 SqueezeBox.open( $('system-message'), {
 handler: 'adopt',
 shadow: true,
 overlayOpacity: 0.5,
 size: {x: 600, y: 100},
 onOpen: function(){
 $('system-message').setStyle('visibility', 'visible');
 }
 });
 }
});
</script>

<!--[if IE 7]>
      <link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/css/ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <![endif]-->

</head>
<div id="maincont">

<body>
  <!-- no javascript warning -->
 <noscript><div id="noscript">
  <p class="noscriptnotice">IMPORTANT NOTICE</p><br />
  <p>You Have Javascript Disabled - Important Features Of The test Site Require Javascript To Work </p><br />
 <p>Please Enable Javascript - <a href="#" title="x">x</a></p></div></noscript>

<div id="container">
  <div id="ht_login">
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="ht_login" style="xhtml"/>
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="top_cart" style="xhtml"/>

  </div>
  <!-- end login -->

  <div id="header">
  <a href="http://www.test.com"> </a></div>
  <!-- end header -->
  <div id="topnav">
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="topnav" style="xhtml"/>
  </div>
  <!-- end top nav -->
  <div id="subnav">
    <?php if( $this->countModules('position-0') ) : ?>
    <div id="searchbox">
      <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-0" style="xhtml"/>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <!-- end search box nav -->

    <?php if( $this->countModules('position-1') ) : ?>
    <div id="socialbuttons">
      <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-1" style="xhtml"/>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <!-- end social buttons nav -->
  </div>

  <!-- end sub nav -->
  <div id="breadcrumbs">
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="breadcrumbs" style="xhtml"/>
  </div>
  <!-- end breadcrumbs -->
    <div id="leftcolcontwrap">
  <div id="leftcol">
    <?php if( $this->countModules('position-2') ) : ?>
    <div id="leftcoltop">
      <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-2" style="xhtml"/>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <!-- end left col top -->

    <?php if( $this->countModules('position-3') ) : ?>
    <div id="leftcolmid">
      <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-3" style="xhtml"/>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <!-- end left col mid -->
    <?php if( $this->countModules('position-4') ) : ?>
    <div id="leftcolbot">
      <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-4" style="xhtml"/>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <!-- end left col bot -->
    <?php if( $this->countModules('position-5') ) : ?>
    <div id="leftcolbot2">
      <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-5" style="xhtml"/>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <!-- end left col bot2 -->
  </div>
  <!-- end left col -->

  <div id="content">
    <jdoc:include type="message" />
    <jdoc:include type="component" />
  </div>
    <!-- end content -->
<div class="clr"></div>    </div>

  <!-- end left_col_cont_wrap -->
  <div id="footer">



<ul class="top">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>

      </ul>  

<ul class="bot">
            <li><</li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>

      </ul>  
      </div>
  <!-- end footer -->

</div>
<!-- end container -->
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="debug" />
</body>
  </div>

</html>
```

---

Thanks

Comment: This is an HTML + CSS question. Please DO NOT post your server-side source code. No one can run it, so they can't help answer your question. Show only the relevant HTML + CSS output.

Comment: Sorry, I am new at posting code.

Answer (score 1):

IE7 might be having a problem parsing your markup...

```
<div id="maincont">

<body>
```

You're opening a DIV then starting your BODY tag.

Comment: I fixed the div. The problem persists.